# Remove item from array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Seen this question a lot, but cannot find something that's what i'm looking for.

`onClick` I push an item to an array I have, however, if there's 3 items in my array I don't want to be able to push items anymore.

```
var selectedData = [];
```

I set my empty variable.

```
var index = selectedData.indexOf(3);
```

I then get the index of my array which is 3

```
if (index > 3) {
  selectedData.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Then within my `if statement` I say, if my index which is 3, is bigger then 3, then splice at `index` and remove one.

```
selectedData.push(TheThing);
```

I then push `TheThing` to my array if the if statement above isn't true.

However, I have a variable `var arrayLength = selectedData.length;` that grabs the length, and when I console log it, it starts at `0` and splices items anything after 4. Not 3.

Any idea what i've done wrong or misunderstood?
Thanks

---

More full example of my code

```
var selectedData = [];

myElement.on('click', function() {

  var index = selectedData.indexOf(3);
      if (index > 3) {
          selectedData.splice(index, 1);
      }
  var arrayLength = selectedData.length;

  console.log(arrayLength, 'the length');

});
```

So in short, `onClick` check my array and remove anything after the third that gets added into my array.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: put your code along with this type of questions

Comment: Sorry, i'll update question now.

Comment: I don't completely get what you're trying to do with the splice, but something like `if (selectedData.length < 3) selectedData.push(TheThing);` will probably work better compared to messing with indexes for only pushing when you don't have 3 elements in the array.

Comment: Just updated question, i'll give your suggestion a try @Shilly I'm basically, adding items to an array. But if there's three items in the array I don't want to add anything. However, the index starts at 0. So it's counting my items I add into the array as 4 not 3 so the splice I put in at 3 only removes items in the array after the 4th item in

Comment: change to `.indexOf(2);`

Comment: @Shilly Ahh I guess that's a better method of handling it instead of removing it from the array every time. Works as I wanted as well, thank you!

Comment: since you're not doing anything with the part of the array you splice out, you might as well just use `if (selectedData.length >= 3) selectedData = [];` to reset the array to an empty one or replace the last element by the new element if that's what you're trying. Sidenote: Only use indexOf to get the index of an element in the array as many ppl explain, not to check the amount of elements in the array.

Comment: @Shilly Thanks! I went about it the wrong way, I was grabbing the `.length` and then getting the `index` of an item which is the 4th in the array and trying to remove the 4th item every time. Not the best method I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this to behave as a stack or a queue?

So your code here:

```
var index = selectedData.indexOf(3);
```

Is not grabbing the 3rd index - its grabbing the first index where it sees 3, or -1 if it doesn't.  Replace your if statement with,

```
if (selectedData.length > 3) {
    selectedData.pop() // removes last element (stack)
    // or
    selectedData = selectedData.slice(1) //remove first element (queue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try `var arrayLength = selectedData.length -1;`

You start at 0 like a normal array, but don't you start with an empty array?

Plus when you use `.length`, it returns the true count of the array or collection not a 0 index.
`

Answer (score 0):

you can override `push()` method of your array like this:

```
var a = [];
a.push = function(){}
```

or like this

```
a.push = function (newEl){
  if(this.length <3){
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, newEl)
  }
}
```

This is not complete example because push() can take many arguments and you should to handle this case too

Answer (score 0):

var index = selectedData.indexOf(3); simply give you the index of the element of the array that has value 3
Example

```
 selectedData = [ 0, 3 , 2];
 alert( selectedData.indexOf( 3 ) ); // this will alert "1" that is the index of the element with value "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this scenario

```
var selectedData = [];

myElement.on('click', function() {

  //if selectedData length is less than 3, push items

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work.

```
myElement.on('click', function() {

    if(selectedData.length > 3){
        selectedData = selectedData.splice(0, 3);
    }

    console.log(selectedData.length, 'the length');

});
```